# Estilos con PhpSpreadSheets

Tags: php, excel, phpspreadsheet

Estoy intentando generar reportes desde mysql con phpspreadsheet pero tengo la duda de como aplicar estilo por cada hoja de calculo que genero. Hasta el momento solo logro aplicarle el estilo a la primer hoja, pero a la segunda no le produce ningún cambio. Saben como puedo resolverlo?
Anexo el código que estoy utilizando para hacer pruebas.

```php
<?php

require __DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php";

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Border;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Fill;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Style;

$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
//$spreadsheet->getSheetByName('Resumen');
$spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
    ->getSheetByName('Resumen')
    ->setCellValue('A1', 'Hola')
    ->setCellValue('B2', 'Mundo!');

//$myWorkSheet = new Worksheet($spreadsheet, 'My Data');
//$spreadsheet->getSheetByName('Detalle');
$spreadsheet->createSheet(1)
->getSheetByName('Detalle')
    ->setCellValue('A1', 'Prueba')
    ->setCellValue('B2', 'Prueba!');

$sharedStyle2 = new Style();
$sharedStyle2->applyFromArray(
    ['fill' => [
                'fillType' => Fill::FILL_SOLID,
                'color' => ['argb' => 'FFCCFFCC'],
            ],
            'borders' => [
                'bottom' => ['borderStyle' => Border::BORDER_THIN],
                'right' => ['borderStyle' => Border::BORDER_MEDIUM],
            ],
        ]
);

$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->duplicateStyle($sharedStyle2, 'A1:T100');

header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="salida.xlsx"');
$writer = IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');
$writer->save('php://output');
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Logre solucionar mi problema, comparto mi codigo por si le es util a alguien

```php
<?php

//Consultas
$consulta=mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT r.Id_Campana, cm.Campana, cm.Hora_Inicio, cm.Hora_Fin, MIN(r.PrimerLlamada) AS PrimerLlamada, MAX(r.UltimaLlamada) AS UltimaLlamada, r.CallerId, count(r.Id_Credito) AS TotalCredito, count(r.Telefono) AS TotalTelefono, SUM(r.LlamadasExitosas) AS LlamadasExitosas
FROM SGbl.BL_201909_rbt r
JOIN SGbl.BL_201909_rbt_CM cm ON r.Id_Campana=cm.Id_Campana
WHERE cm.Fecha_Inicio=20190903 AND
cm.Campana='Sol_Blaster_I5'
GROUP BY cm.Id_Campana;");
$array=mysqli_fetch_array($consulta);
$fila=8;

$consulta1=mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT r.Id_Campana, cm.Campana, r.Fecha_Registro, cm.Fecha_Inicio, cm.Fecha_Fin, cm.Hora_Inicio, cm.Hora_Fin, r.CallerId, r.Id_Credito, r.Telefono, r.PrimerLlamada, r.UltimaLlamada, r.LlamadasExitosas
FROM SGbl.BL_201909_rbt r
JOIN SGbl.BL_201909_rbt_CM cm ON r.Id_Campana=cm.Id_Campana
WHERE cm.Fecha_Inicio=20190903 AND
cm.Campana='Sol_Blaster_I5';");
$array1=mysqli_fetch_array($consulta1);
$fila5=2;



//Fecha actual
date_default_timezone_set('GMT');
$fecha= date("d-M-Y");

//Composer
require __DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php";

//Librerias
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Border;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Fill;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Style;

//Crear un nuevo archivo
$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();

//Propiedades del archivo
$spreadsheet->getProperties()->setCreator('Sistemas')
    ->setTitle('Reporte de Herramientas Blaster')
    ->setDescription('Test document for Office 2007 XLSX, generated using PHP classes.');

//Informacion de la campaña
$spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()
    ->setTitle('Resumen')
    ->setCellValue('A1', 'Reporte de Herramientas Blaster')
    ->setCellValue('A2', $fecha)
    ->setCellValue('A3', 'Campaña Isla 5');

 $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:A3')->getFont()->setBold(true)->setSize(18);

//Encabezados del resumen
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()
    ->mergeCells('C5:L5')
    ->mergeCells('C6:D6')
    ->mergeCells('E6:I6')
    ->mergeCells('J6:L6')
    ->setCellValue('C5', 'RESUMEN DE LA CAMPAÑA ISLA 5')
    ->setCellValue('C6', 'IDENTIFICADORES')
    ->setCellValue('E6', 'FECHAS')
    ->setCellValue('J6', 'METRICAS POR HORA')
    ->setCellValue('C7', 'ID de Campaña')
    ->setCellValue('D7', 'Nombre de Campaña')
    ->setCellValue('E7', 'Hora de Inicio')
    ->setCellValue('F7', 'Hora Fin')
    ->setCellValue('G7', 'Primer Llamada')
    ->setCellValue('H7', 'Ultima Llamada')
    ->setCellValue('I7', 'Telefono de Contacto')
    ->setCellValue('J7', 'Total de Creditos')
    ->setCellValue('K7', 'Telefonos Programadas')
    ->setCellValue('L7', 'Llamadas Exitosas');

$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('C5:L5')->getFont()->setBold(true)->setSize(20);
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('C6:L6')->getFont()->setBold(true)->setSize(12);
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('C5:L5')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal('center');
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('C6:D6')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal('center');
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('E6:I6')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal('center');
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('J6:L6')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal('center');
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('C')->setAutoSize(true);
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('D')->setAutoSize(true);
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('E')->setAutoSize(true);
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('F')->setAutoSize(true);
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('G')->setAutoSize(true);
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('H')->setAutoSize(true);
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('I')->setAutoSize(true);
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('J')->setAutoSize(true);
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('K')->setAutoSize(true);
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('L')->setAutoSize(true);
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('M')->setAutoSize(true);
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('C7')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal('center');
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('D7')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal('center');
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('E7')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal('center');
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('F7')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal('center');
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('G7')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal('center');
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('H7')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal('center');
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('I7')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal('center');
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('J7')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal('center');
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('K7')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal('center');
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('L7')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal('center');
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('C5:L7')->getFill()->setFillType(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setARGB('9FD5D1');
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('C5:L7')->getFont()->getColor()->setRGB('FFFFFF');

//Datos de la base
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)) {
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()
    ->setCellValue('C'.$fila, $row['Id_Campana'])
    ->setCellValue('D'.$fila, $row['Campana'])
    ->setCellValue('E'.$fila, $row['Hora_Inicio'])
    ->setCellValue('F'.$fila, $row['Hora_Fin'])
    ->setCellValue('G'.$fila, $row['PrimerLlamada'])
    ->setCellValue('H'.$fila, $row['UltimaLlamada'])
    ->setCellValue('I'.$fila, $row['CallerId'])
    ->setCellValue('J'.$fila, $row['TotalCredito'])
    ->setCellValue('K'.$fila, $row['TotalTelefono'])
    ->setCellValue('L'.$fila, $row['LlamadasExitosas']);

$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('C'.$fila.'')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal('center');
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('D'.$fila.'')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal('center');
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('E'.$fila.'')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal('center');
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('F'.$fila.'')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal('center');
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('G'.$fila.'')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal('center');
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('H'.$fila.'')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal('center');
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('I'.$fila.'')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal('center');
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('J'.$fila.'')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal('center');
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('K'.$fila.'')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal('center');
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('L'.$fila.'')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal('center');
$fila++;
}
$fila1 = $fila + 1;
$fila2 = $fila1 + 1;
$fila3 = $fila2 + 1;

//Encabezados Formulas
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()
    ->mergeCells('C'.$fila1.':L'.$fila1.'')
    ->mergeCells('C'.$fila2.':D'.$fila2.'')
    ->mergeCells('E'.$fila2.':F'.$fila2.'')
    ->mergeCells('G'.$fila2.':H'.$fila2.'')
    ->mergeCells('I'.$fila2.':J'.$fila2.'')
    ->mergeCells('K'.$fila2.':L'.$fila2.'')
    ->setCellValue('C'.$fila1.'', 'METRICAS TOTALES')
    ->setCellValue('C'.$fila2.'', 'Total de Campañas')
    ->setCellValue('E'.$fila2.'', 'Total de Creditos')
    ->setCellValue('G'.$fila2.'', 'Total de Telefonos')
    ->setCellValue('I'.$fila2.'', 'Llamadas Exitosas')
    ->setCellValue('K'.$fila2.'', 'Llamadas Fallidas');

$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('C'.$fila1.':L'.$fila1.'')->getFont()->setBold(true)->setSize(12);
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('C'.$fila1.':L'.$fila1.'')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal('center');
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('C'.$fila2.':D'.$fila2.'')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal('center');
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('E'.$fila2.':F'.$fila2.'')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal('center');
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('G'.$fila2.':H'.$fila2.'')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal('center');
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('I'.$fila2.':J'.$fila2.'')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal('center');
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('K'.$fila2.':L'.$fila2.'')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal('center');
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('C'.$fila1.':L'.$fila2.'')->getFill()->setFillType(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setARGB('9FD5D1');
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('C'.$fila1.':L'.$fila2.'')->getFont()->getColor()->setRGB('FFFFFF');

//Formulas
$fila4 = $fila - 1;
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()
    ->mergeCells('C'.$fila3.':D'.$fila3.'')
    ->mergeCells('E'.$fila3.':F'.$fila3.'')
    ->mergeCells('G'.$fila3.':H'.$fila3.'')
    ->mergeCells('I'.$fila3.':J'.$fila3.'')
    ->mergeCells('K'.$fila3.':L'.$fila3.'')
    ->setCellValue('C'.$fila3.'', '=COUNTA(C8:C'.$fila4.')')
    ->setCellValue('E'.$fila3.'', '=SUMPRODUCT(J8:J'.$fila4.')')
    ->setCellValue('G'.$fila3.'', '=SUMPRODUCT(K8:K'.$fila4.')')
    ->setCellValue('I'.$fila3.'', '=SUMPRODUCT(L8:L'.$fila4.')')
    ->setCellValue('K'.$fila3.'', '=(G'.$fila3.'- I'.$fila3.')');

$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('C'.$fila3.':D'.$fila3.'')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal('center');
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('E'.$fila3.':F'.$fila3.'')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal('center');
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('G'.$fila3.':H'.$fila3.'')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal('center');
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('I'.$fila3.':J'.$fila3.'')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal('center');
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('K'.$fila3.':L'.$fila3.'')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal('center');

//HOJA DE DETALLE
//Envabezados
$spreadsheet->createSheet();
$spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(1);
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()
    ->setTitle('Detalle')
    ->setCellValue('A1', 'ID Campaña')
    ->setCellValue('B1', 'Nombre de la Campaña')
    ->setCellValue('C1', 'Fecha de Registro')
    ->setCellValue('D1', 'Fecha Inicio')
    ->setCellValue('E1', 'Fecha Fin')
    ->setCellValue('F1', 'Hora Inicio')
    ->setCellValue('G1', 'Hora Fin')
    ->setCellValue('H1', 'Telefono de Contacto')
    ->setCellValue('I1', 'ID Credito')
    ->setCellValue('J1', 'Telefono')
    ->setCellValue('K1', 'Primer Llamada')
    ->setCellValue('L1', 'Ultima Llamada')
    ->setCellValue('M1', 'Llamadas Exitosas');

$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:M1')->getFont()->setBold(true)->setSize(12);
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setAutoSize(true);
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('B')->setAutoSize(true);
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('C')->setAutoSize(true);
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('D')->setAutoSize(true);
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('F')->setAutoSize(true);
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('G')->setAutoSize(true);
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('H')->setAutoSize(true);
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('I')->setAutoSize(true);
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('J')->setAutoSize(true);
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('K')->setAutoSize(true);
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('L')->setAutoSize(true);
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('M')->setAutoSize(true);
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal('center');
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B1')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal('center');
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('C1')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal('center');
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('D1')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal('center');
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('E1')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal('center');
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('F1')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal('center');
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('G1')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal('center');
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('H1')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal('center');
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('I1')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal('center');
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('J1')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal('center');
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('K1')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal('center');
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('L1')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal('center');
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('M1')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal('center');
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:M1')->getFill()->setFillType(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setARGB('9FD5D1');
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:M1')->getFont()->getColor()->setRGB('FFFFFF');
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->freezePane('A2');

//Impresion de datos desde la base
while ($row1=mysqli_fetch_array($consulta1)) {
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()
    ->setCellValue('A'.$fila5, $row1['Id_Campana'])
    ->setCellValue('B'.$fila5, $row1['Campana'])
    ->setCellValue('C'.$fila5, $row1['Fecha_Registro'])
    ->setCellValue('D'.$fila5, $row1['Fecha_Inicio'])
    ->setCellValue('E'.$fila5, $row1['Fecha_Fin'])
    ->setCellValue('F'.$fila5, $row1['Hora_Inicio'])
    ->setCellValue('G'.$fila5, $row1['Hora_Fin'])
    ->setCellValue('H'.$fila5, $row1['CallerId'])
    ->setCellValue('I'.$fila5, $row1['Id_Credito'])
    ->setCellValue('J'.$fila5, $row1['Telefono'])
    ->setCellValue('K'.$fila5, $row1['PrimerLlamada'])
    ->setCellValue('L'.$fila5, $row1['UltimaLlamada'])
    ->setCellValue('M'.$fila5, $row1['LlamadasExitosas']);

$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A'.$fila5.'')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal('center');
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B'.$fila5.'')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal('center');
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('C'.$fila5.'')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal('center');
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('D'.$fila5.'')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal('center');
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('E'.$fila5.'')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal('center');
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('F'.$fila5.'')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal('center');
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('G'.$fila5.'')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal('center');
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('H'.$fila5.'')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal('center');
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('I'.$fila5.'')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal('center');
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('J'.$fila5.'')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal('center');
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('K'.$fila5.'')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal('center');
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('L'.$fila5.'')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal('center');
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('M'.$fila5.'')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal('center');
$fila5++;
}

//Generar archivo Excel
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="Reporte Blaster Isla 5.xlsx"');
$writer = IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');
$writer->save('php://output');



/*Congelar fila1
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->freezePane('A2');
*/
?>
```